# Frame Label doesn't show up

Tags: labeling

```
 Module[{labels = {"AIDS", "AIDS ALERT", "AIDS CARE", "AIDS POL & LAW",
 "BMJ", "INT J STD AIDS", "JAIDS", "LANCET", "NEW ENGL J MED", 
 "SAMJ"}, data = {4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3}}, 
 BarChart[data, 
 ChartLabels -> 
 Placed[Sort[labels], {{0.5, 0}, {0.9, 1}}, 
 Rotate[#, 50 Degree, {Right, Center}] &], 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 6}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{20, 0}, {95, 0}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["", FontSize -> 18], 
 Style["nÂº de publicaciones", FontSize -> 18]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{True, None}, {None, None}}]]
```

Why the right-vertical Frame doesn't show up?
Why the left-vertical Framelabel doesn't show up?

Does anybody know how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to play with `ImagePadding`.  Something like `ImagePadding -> {{100, 20}, {95, 20}}`.

Answer (score 2):

They don't show up because you have set the `ImagePadding` option too small.  If you increase those values all the labels show up:

```
Module[
 {
  labels = {"AIDS", "AIDS ALERT", "AIDS CARE", "AIDS POL & LAW", 
    "BMJ", "INT J STD AIDS", "JAIDS", "LANCET", "NEW ENGL J MED", 
    "SAMJ"},
  data = {4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3}
  },
 BarChart[
  data,
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[Sort[labels], {{0.5, 0}, {0.9, 1}}, 
    Rotate[#, 50 Degree, {Right, Center}] &],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 6}},
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {100, 50}},
  Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}},
  FrameLabel -> {Style["", FontSize -> 18], 
    Style["nÂº de publicaciones", FontSize -> 18]},
  FrameTicks -> {{True, None}, {None, None}}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Showing the labels]